# How to chage dockingpanel's title

Tags: autodesk-forge

I want to change panel's title ( create using dockingpanel )

I use method dockingpanel 'setTitle(...)' .

The following error occurred

"
DockingPanel.js:477 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of undefined
at MyPanel.o.setTitle (DockingPanel.js:477)
"

I'd appreciate it if you could tell me how to change the docking panel title

Answer (score 0):

It's almost like that you called `DockinPanel#setTitle` before its supper constructor was called. Please try to call that function after `Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel.call` or `super()`

```
  // es5
  var SimplePanel = function(parentContainer, id, title, content, x, y)
  {
      this.content = content;
      Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel.call(this, parentContainer, id, '');
      // Auto-fit to the content and don't allow resize.  Position at the coordinates given.
      //
      this.container.style.height = "auto";
      this.container.style.width = "auto";
      this.container.style.resize = "none";
      this.container.style.left = x + "px";
      this.container.style.top = y + "px";
    

      // Call setTitle here
  };

  SimplePanel.prototype = Object.create(Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel.prototype);
  SimplePanel.prototype.constructor = SimplePanel;

  // es6
  class SimplePanel extends Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel {
     constructor(parentContainer, id, title, content, x, y) {
       super();

       // Call setTitle here
     }

  }
```